# Telegram API Authentication "Too Fast"

Tags: c#, .net, telegram

I created a telegram client in C# .Net and used telegram API with TeleSharp to Authenticate user with code.
After 4 times telegram doesn't allow me to authenticate my user and says "Too Fast" (wait 24 hours).
Is there a way to authenticate one time and save the code or to create a test client that won't get blocked?

```
 private TelegramClient NewClient()
    {
        try
        {
            return new TelegramClient(793924, "df6abda591c5e87782fe9368f264fdb8");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Credantials Not Valid");
            return null;
        }
    }

    TelegramClient client;
    string hash;

    private async void CodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new TelegramClient(793924, "df6abda591c5e87782fe9368f264fdb8");
        await client.ConnectAsync();
        hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(PhoneText.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Sent!");

    }

    private async void SignButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(PhoneText.Text, hash, CodeText.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        Form1 Main = new Form1(user, client);
        //Form1 Main = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        Main.Show();
    }
```

Comment: why don't you cache the credentials?

Comment: What do you mean? the code is sent every time

Comment: As far as I have seen, they have an excellent documentation. I would be surprised if they didn't cover this in docs or in a tutorial.

Comment: I wasn't able to fine anything related except the repeating authentication

Comment: _"It is best to immediately store the User ID locally in a binding with the key. At some point in time (>= expires), the association will expire, and the authorization process will have to be repeated."_ See https://core.telegram.org/api/auth

Comment: Oh wait ... does this happen on MakeAuthAsync or SendCodeRequestAsync?

Comment: SendCodeRequestAsync

Comment: In that case persist the code it returns and use it until Authentication fails for expired Association, or at least shortly before. ... Well at least not more frequent than 24h, I guess.